# Conditional type inference failing to handle a union with a Promise

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a situation where I'm trying to infer a type parameter that might be wrapped in a Promise, and when I try to represent it as a union that includes `Promise<NonNullable<T>>`, the inference fails to narrow my param (it only works if I pass the entire union as the type parameter for `NonNullable`).

```js
type OuterUnion<T> = NonNullable<T> | Promise<NonNullable<T>>;
type InnerUnion<T> = NonNullable<T | Promise<T>>

function usingOuter<T>(args: T): T extends OuterUnion<infer Y> ? Y | undefined : never {
  return null as any
}

function usingInner<T>(args: T): T extends InnerUnion<infer Y> ? Y | undefined : never {
  return null as any
}

// string | Promise<string> | undefined   :(
const result1 = usingOuter(Promise.resolve('string'))

// string | undefined                     :)
const result2 = usingInner(Promise.resolve('string'))
```

I guess if I completely spell out the return type, I get a very strange looking infer inside a promise, that looks like `T extends Promise<infer Y extends null | undefined ? never : infer Y> ? Y | undefined : never` but I still don't understand the mechanics for why it fails.

Is there a direct reason for this? Thanks in advance for your help!

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsCAnAqgOwJYHs0B4AqAfFALxQByO5cANjQIYBGNEBxAPlAApJYC2GAM6tKaanSYs2hANwAoUJCgBJNGmTpseIqQpVaDZq3xROPfkOOFCcuQDM4aAMbAtUOIIxoA5vERI2AAp6JG9BAC4ofABKSJMIAA9ENAATQVgEDUwcXC87ZCgATWIAfiLTd1SIOy8IFKhI9QA3AoBvOSgoJAhgOCQ0KDQDKHp0+jQQOQBfWwdnVxx3Tx9VdQCiYNCIqNioqETktJU1LK1ctHykItLyzkcU6tr6xogWq-bO7t7+weHRkYm01sAHpgVBBMAkF5vBVzAJhLgIVCfBxKg8aup6p1woE5E4cBCuhBBLRgABGXQeaF+ZCBOGWAB03UEWBoLUCAHIkdCOdFoiCwdyfBV7o9MZ0JZKpdKGvz8WhCczSQAmSnLbyrWn04RM4ms9lcyE8vlAA)

edit: [updated Playground link - the outer union does work if you replace NonNullable with a slightly different implementation which is also strange](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsCAnAqgOwJYHs0B4AqAfFALxQByO5cANjQIYBGNEBxAPlAApJYC2GAM6tKaanSYs2hANwAoUJCgBJNGmTpseIqQpVaDZq3xROPfkOOFCcuQDM4aAMbAtUOIIxoA5vERI2AAp6JG9BAC4ofABKSJMIAA9ENAATQVgEDUwcXC87ZCgATWIAfiLTd1SIOy8IFKhI9QA3AoBvOSgoJAhgOCQ0KDQDKHp0+jQQOQBfWwdnVxx3Tx9VdQCiYNCIqNioqETktJU1LK1ctHykItLyzkcU6tr6xogWq-bO7t7+weHRkYm01sAHpgVBBMAkF5vBVzAJhLgIVCfBxKg8aup6p1woE5E4cBCuhBBLRgABGXQeaF+ZCBOGWAB03UEWBoLUCAHIkdCOdFoiCwdyfBV7o9MZ0JZKpdKGvz8WhCczSQAmSnLbyrWn04RM4ms9lcyE8vm2OSgqAoLgAEQAgvgAKKRJzjIlgBhOaCicSGFhQRggKBOAAWECcAGtoVAMHY9gcIKl0q0ZopoAB9L0GSRWXTxJLxo5JqBlEwvN4KcBpmmobLaYhkdP6CRGNiw3jw1gNsSZ5tEWT2RwuNypqk+KtBEJhOK7XOHdKpquaHJ5ArFIu3NFiuoNQavNodInfAZDOgjMaAmbyxXE0kAZl0w-VVbpbcZzP1EE5Qu8vOiQA)

disclaimer: my actual use case is more complicated which is why I'm using conditional type inference in the first place (args is a variadic tuple where `Y` can be different types like `string` | `number` etc where the order matters). I tried to whittle it down to the simplest reproducible example which probably comes across very contrived here.

Comment: The plot thickens: If I replace the regular NonNullable implementation - `T extends undefined | null ?  never : T` - with the inverse: `T extends {} ? T : never` Then the "outer-union" is able to infer past the promise correctly.

Added a second TS Playground link in my question to illustrate